# ZUUL HTTPS routing failing with SSL handshake exception

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a spring boot app with zuul in place for in-app routing. This is a single ear deployment with 2 war files in it. WAR A will reach out to WAR B for data. This is where I am using zuul routing. 
When the URL is a simple http://server_name:unsecure_port/route it worked fine. Now I have changed it to https://server_name:secured_port/route and generated keystores/truststores and set the properties in application.yml file. The exception I see is ssl handshake failure. I have added JVM arguments as follows -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2. Kinldy help. My first post, Please accept my apologies if the format is incorrect or data is not sufficient.

UPDATE: I have a new exception, info added at the end. Also, I am able to make a successful connection to the https server from my local workspace app which is http. Now the failure and exceptions I added are coming when the https_server call is being made from https_ui on the same server. Thought adding this would make more sense and gives insight into my problem.

```
zuul:
   routes:
     serviceName:
       path: /route/**
       url: https://<server_name>:<secure_port>/<forwarding_to_here>


Exception:

[5/4/20 12:45:45:945 EDT] 000000de SystemOut     O 2020-05-04T12:45:45,939:tainer : 5 [WARN ] Error during filtering
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.handleException(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:220) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4217) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2208) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:782) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.i(av.java:574) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:280) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.startHandshake(av.java:431) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:390) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:309) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:215) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 120 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:231) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:579) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.i(av.java:574) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:280) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.av.startHandshake(av.java:431) ~[?:8.0 build_20181010]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:390) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:309) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:215) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 120 more


Updated Exception: I have enabled debug through jvm arguments, now I see below errors in addition to what I had already added as exceptions.

[5/5/20 13:23:01:964 EDT] 000000d6 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 5, fatal error: 40: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported
[5/5/20 13:23:01:964 EDT] 000000d6 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 5, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
[5/5/20 13:23:01:964 EDT] 000000d6 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 5, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[5/5/20 13:23:01:964 EDT] 000000d6 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 5, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported
[5/5/20 13:23:01:966 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 3, received EOFException: error
[5/5/20 13:23:01:966 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
[5/5/20 13:23:01:966 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 3, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
[5/5/20 13:23:01:966 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[5/5/20 13:23:01:966 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O [Raw write]: length = 7
[5/5/20 13:23:01:966 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O 0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               .......

[5/5/20 13:23:01:966 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O WebContainer : 3, called closeSocket()
[5/5/20 13:23:01:967 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O 2020-05-05T13:23:01,967:tainer : 3 [DEBUG] http-outgoing-1: Shutdown connection
[5/5/20 13:23:01:967 EDT] 000000d4 SystemOut     O 2020-05-05T13:23:01,967:tainer : 3 [DEBUG] Connection discarded
```

Comment: please post the full exception

Comment: Hello @spencergibb. Thanks for your response. Please look at the updated post with full exception. Thank you.

Comment: are you using self signed certificates?

Comment: @spencergibb That is correct. I am using self signed certs. I think I caught a break through on this. I will post details after documenting them. More related towards configuring TLS on WebSphere and editing the config files on server along with settings. Thank you.

Comment: The zuul http client or jdk needs to be configured with the self-signed certs

Comment: FIXED: I have added the following property in custom properties of WAS com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true and following to the JVM arguments to make server and client follow the same TLS version : -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2